# Xml Error Invalid Token

Tags: xml

```
<entries>
<entry>
        <IMAGE><![CDATA[img52.jpg]]></IMAGE>
        <ID><![CDATA[5242]]></ID>
        <TITLE><![CDATA[Shawshank redemption…]]></TITLE>
</entry>
<entries>
```

I have above xml being sent by an API that I don't have any control to. This xml gives me invalid token for "…"  I suspect real dots as I am typing it here should be "...".

How can I fix this error on my end.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
  <ID><![CDATA[5242]]></OID>
```

with

```
   <ID><![CDATA[5242]]></ID>
```

also at end

```
</entries>
```

Comment: Sorry That was the type the error is given at line <TITLE><![CDATA[Shawshank redemption…]]></TITLE>  I think it is due "…".

Comment: these error i have mentioned is also an error in your xml 

if you want to make it sure test your this xml code in xml tester.

Comment: Yes I have corrected it was typo while pasting the code here.See the edited answer.Actually it is just like you said.Error is still there.

Comment: if my answer is correct then kindly tick my answer.

Comment: Your answer is correct for that part but after correcting that part I have pasted the xml here on http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp and still getting this error :--error at line 7 at column 10 extra content at end of document.